# qemu: how to get image UUID

Tags: libvirt, mount-point

I want to mount a existing image (`file.vhd`) to a running guest:

```
<!-- attach.xml -->
<disk type='file' device='disk'>
    <driver name='qemu' type='vpc' cache='none' io='native' dataplane='on' />
    <source file='/path/to/file.vhd'/>
    <target dev='vdf'/>
</disk>
```

then

```
# virsh attach-device guest1 attach.xml
```

here, I want to mount `file.vhd` to `guest1` and under `/dev/vdf`, but when there is only two device existed on `guest1`, `file.vhd` will mount to `/dev/vdc` (`/dev/vda` and `/dev/vbd` has been occupied by existing 2 disk), so I can't know where `file.vhd` will be mounted without login into `guest1` for checking.

How to make it possible to know the mount point before I mount `file.vhd`?

*By the way, at the same time, there may be other client attach `some.vhd` to `guest1`, so just check the next mount point on `guest1` remotely **may not** work.*

I know the `lsblk` can list device's UUID like this:

```
# lsblk -nio NAME,UUID
```

I don't know if the UUID is existed within the `file.vhd` before I attached to `guest1` or only generated by `guest1`. If the UUID is existed within `file.vhd`, how to get it?

I have tried mount the same `file.vhd` file to `guest1` multiple times (with different `/dev/vd*`), it seems that the UUID of them are the same, so I think the UUID may existed within `file.vhd`, but I still not sure definitely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

libguestfs provides a set of tools for manipulating / inspecting disk images. This is capable of reporting the label & UUID associated with any filesystems inside a guest disk image. e.g. http://libguestfs.org/virt-filesystems.1.html

```
 $ virt-filesystems -a win.img --all --long --uuid -h
 Name      Type       VFS  Label           Size Parent   UUID
 /dev/sda1 filesystem ntfs System Reserved 100M -        F81C92571C92112C
 /dev/sda2 filesystem ntfs -               20G  -        F2E8996AE8992E3B
 /dev/sda1 partition  -    -               100M /dev/sda -
 /dev/sda2 partition  -    -               20G  /dev/sda -
 /dev/sda  device     -    -               20G  -        -
```

A possibly simpler alternative to this though (particularly if you just have a single partition in the disk), is to specify a unique serial string in the disk XML e.g.

```
<disk type='file' device='disk'>
    <driver name='qemu' type='vpc' cache='none' io='native' dataplane='on' />
    <source file='/path/to/file.vhd'/>
    <serial>XXXXXXXXXX</serial>
    <target dev='vdf'/>
</disk>
```

The text in the serial field gets included in the /dev/disk/by-path symlinks, allowing you to have a predictable device name to mount it with.

Comment: Once `serial` is assigned, I can use `udevadm` to loop all devices for the `serial`: `udevadm info --query=property --name=/dev/vd[a-z] | grep 'ID_SERIAL='`